# Stacked Barplot inside Table in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to plot stacked bar plot inside table in latex.

I have code which plots two different bar plots inside table. But i want to plot single barplot with stacked bars.

How can I do it in LATEX ?

Many thanks...

Here is the code.......

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}    
\usepackage{filecontents}

% The data
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
accession,data1,data2
C1,150708.4564,481.0388003
C2,49652.53112,275.2190163
C3,37379.1284,58.85806921
C4,34165.85698,26.06571636
C5,30856.19158,35.96802428
C6,15204.22768,26.71594573
\end{filecontents}


\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.txt}\data

\newcommand{\errplota}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis right]
  \begin{axis}[y=-\baselineskip,
  scale only axis,
  width=5cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  axis y line*=middle,
  ytick=\empty,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  xbar,
  bar width=1.5ex,
  xmin=0,
  visualization depends on=x \as \rawx,
  nodes near coords,
  every node near coord/.style={
  anchor=east,
  shift={(axis direction cs:-\rawx,0)}
 }
 ]
% 
\addplot [draw=black, fill=red]
 table [x=data1,y expr=\coordindex]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
 \newcommand{\errplotb}{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis right]
 \begin{axis}[y=-\baselineskip,
  scale only axis,
  width=5cm,
  enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
  axis y line*=middle,
  ytick=\empty,
  axis x line*=bottom,
  xbar,
  bar width=1.5ex,
  xmin=0,
  visualization depends on=x \as \rawx,
  nodes near coords,
  every node near coord/.style={
  anchor=east,
  shift={(axis direction cs:-\rawx,0)}
 }
 ]
% 
\addplot [draw=black, fill=yellow]
 table [x=data2,y expr=\coordindex]{\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

% Get number of rows in datafile
 \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\data}
\let\numberofrows=\pgfplotsretval

% Print the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset[columns={accession,data1,data2},
 % Booktabs rules
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=[3ex]\bottomrule},
 % Set header name
  columns/accession/.style={string type,column type=l,column name=accession},
  columns/data1/.style={
  column name={Data1},
  assign cell content/.code={% use \multirow for Z column:
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
  {\multirow{\numberofrows}{6.5cm}{\errplota}}%
  \else
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
  \fi
  },}, 
  columns/data2/.style={
  column name={Data2},
  assign cell content/.code={% use \multirow for Z column:
  \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=0
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}
  {\multirow{\numberofrows}{6.5cm}{\errplotb}}%
  \else
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
  \fi
  },
 }
 ]{\data}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: The question was to plot stacked bar plot.

Comment: The values of your first data series are orders of magnitude larger than those of your second series. You won't be able to see the second series in a stacked plot.